# How to stop people stealing from my website?

Tags: web-services, security

I consider myself newbie when it comes to securing my web applications. 
I have built a website which updates the webpages regularly through an AJAX call. The Ajax call returns a decent JSON object to be used at the client side.

There is a simple problem I need to overcome: How can I prevent other people to use the same AJAX call without permission? What if they build a website, AND **at the client side** they allow their users to make the same AJAX call to my servers and grab what they need.. AND THEN parse it to their own needs **at the client side**?

I cannot put an extra layer of security like user authentication.

Comment: Unless you verify the user in some way (for instance: the same IP has requested a full page no longer the X amount of time ago, or a rotating hash/pass changed daily/hourly/whenever), there is no way you can prohibit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They won't be able to actually do this from the client directly because the browser will prevent cross domain AJAX requests for anything other than JSONP (scripts).  That said, they can proxy it on their server if they want so it doesn't buy you much.

ASP.NET MVC has an [antiforgery token mechanism](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/) that you should look at for inspiration.  The basic idea is that you use both an encrypted cookie and an encrypted, hidden form input containing the same data that you write to each page that you want to secure.  Do your AJAX calls using a POST and make sure to send back the form input.  On the server-side decrypt the cookie and input and compare the data to ensure they're the same.  Since the cookie is tied to your domain, it will be much harder to inject in the request that is being sent back.  Use SSL and regenerate the cookie/input content periodically to make it even harder to fake the cookie/input.

Comment: I think it's the right answer: AJAX request can't be cross-site.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the HTTP_REFERER http header and see if the request originates from your page. This can however be spoofed, so don't think of it as a bulletproof solution. The best counter-meassure is user authentication, really.

Answer (score 2):

**You can't.** That's because you can't differenciate between an AJAX call from your web app and another user's webapp.

Here are some things that might help *a little bit*.

- Obscuring/encrypting your AJAX response. This fails mainly because you have to include the decryption code in your app as well.
- Check the IP origin. If the IP didn't access your server before, you can assume that the AJAX call is not from your website. This doesn't work if a) the user switches the IP while being on your site / timing out or b) if another website sends a fake http request first before using your AJAX API.
- Another idea would be to send Javascript instead of a JSON object. The Javascript should contain all the logic needed to update your website, and of course could check if the website is your own. *(window.location)*. That has some disadvantages though: more work for you, higher traffic load and it can be broken anyways.

I don't think it's a bad thing actually. Another website could have just as easily scraped the info from your website.

Answer (score 1):

If by "stealing" you mean getting some content from your website (using HTTP GET), that's more or less the same problem as **hot-linking**. You could have some basic protection technique using the HTTP `Referer` header (it can be worked around, but it works in most cases).

The other problem you have (making sure the requests come from your application) have to do with **CSRF** (Cross-Site Request Forgery). There are various protection mechanisms against this, mostly based on embedding tokens in forms for example.

You could potentially combine the two approaches, although the real protection against getting the content would come from **user authentication** (otherwise, the other site could also get the page from which you're delivering those tokens and proxy it).

(In addition, techniques that rely on remembering the IP address would probably not work well in the whole web architecture: it might cause problems if you get a pool of proxy servers or if the client is a mobile device that may change IP address between various requests, which would be perfectly legitimate.)